# Preventing opera mouse gestures

Tags: javascript, events, mouse, opera

Is it possible to prevent opera mouse gestures for right button? I have web app on html5 and I decided to use right mouse button. But it doesnt work in opera, because opera has mouse gestures.

> event.preventDefault(); // it doesn't work

May be anybody knows?

Thank you.

Comment: This is just a personal experience, but I would find it _VERY_ annoying if my mouse gestures were turned off. I tend to use my mouse a lot and having to leave it to use my keyboard really disrupts my browsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't actually have anything to do with gestures specifically.  Opera doesn't allow scripts to detect context menu events by default so you'd have to ask users to change their site preferences for your site to allow scripts to detect context menu events.

Right click -> Edit Site Preferences -> Scripting (tab) -> Allow scripts to detect context menu events

Comment: If it were possible to override user settings in a script, that would be much more sad.  Edit: where'd your comment go?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I accidentally deleted it, sorry.

Comment: If your new features are worth it, your Opera users will probably change their settings to get them if you let them know about the features.  I let Google maps get right clicks because they have useful stuff in that menu, for example.  It does occasionally interfere with my gestures, but I'm willing to put up with it.