# Mouse gestures enabled?

Tags: javascript, opera

Is there any way to detect with javascript whether someone has enabled his mouse gestures in opera?
Disabling would be the better solution for me, but I already found out, that it is not possible with javascript.

Comment: Can I ask why you care if someone has them on?

Comment: Of course you can. I'm building an application with a canvas and the user can interact with the mouse. And to give the user the best experience I want to recommend to disable the gestures temporarily with a simple `window.alert(...)`. I could just detect, whether the user is using opera, but then he would get the message every time he is using the right mouse button, whether or not the gestures are disabled.

Comment: Most of the materials I see online say its not possible.  v10.5+ has context menu event override option enabled by default, but JavaScript cannot hook into gestures.  http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html : "Mouse Buttons and Default Events" breaks it down pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to do that, and according to [Preventing opera mouse gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012383/preventing-opera-mouse-gestures) you can't get right click events at all in opera without the user allowing it.

You will probably have to give a special message for opera users asking them to enable right clicks for you.