# How to disable Opera mouse gestures?

Tags: javascript, html, mouse, opera, gesture

I'm working on a browser game, where you use right click also. It works fine, but in Opera it's unplayable because of mouse gestures. How can I disable it on my website?

Comment: Maybe if you attach custom events for gesture events and prevent default. But I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012383/preventing-opera-mouse-gestures

Comment: @ChrisFletcher This is not duplicate. This question is about mouse gestures, the question you're talking about is about firing `oncontextmenu` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Menu:

```
Tools > Preferences...  (Ctrl+F12)
```

Uncheck shortcut options in the Dialog:

```
Advanced > Shortcuts > Enable mouse gestures

Advanced > Shortcuts > Enable single-key shortcuts
```

Comment: I cant do it on the client's computer

Comment: Sorry, @DannyFox, but I guess you'll have to ask client politely to disable the gestures while playing the game.

Comment: I'm an Opera User and would love being able to disable gestures for specific websites or give a website the ability to specifically disable these gestures.