# How to disable Opera's right-click drag gestures programmatically?

Tags: javascript, opera, gestures

```
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

While the above code overrides the "right click menu" as intended, it seems, Opera have right-click gestures, so when you hold down the "right-click" button, and swipe left, the browser goes back

In a game where the "right click" is utilised, this results in unintentional Back/Forward events repeatedly

I'm looking for a programmatic solution to fix this issue, are there any events fired that can be caught and prevented?

Ps. I'm aware there are very old questions that try to solve the same issue: [How to disable Opera mouse gestures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520880/how-to-disable-opera-mouse-gestures) - If there is still no programmatic solution to this issue, I will add a warning to my game to nudge people to use Chrome instead

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude how so?

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
var w = window;
$(w).mousedown(function () {

    if (w.opera || navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera|OPR\//))
        $(this).bind("mousemove", function () {
            return false;
        });
    }

});
```

Note: A right click will be captured with mousedown.

Comment: Nice idea, but didn't work - I also tried other variations, they didn't work either :(