# prevent mouse gesture in Opera

Tags: opera-extension

Is there any way with JS to cancel mouse gesture?
not permanently, but only when needed, eg. in certain frame, event..
I tried `onmousemove`

```
return false;
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

nothing helped, gesture is fired every time

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012383/preventing-opera-mouse-gestures

Comment: that question is about Opera on Presto engine, this is about Opera on Blink